Rearrange Table using Postgres
I have a table like this:
I have this postgres table.



date
sender_type
content




1
PATIENT
A


2
PATIENT
B


3
USER
C


4
PATIENT
D


5
PATIENT
E


6
PATIENT
F


7
USER
G


8
USER
H



I want an output like this



sender_type
content




PATIENT
A,B


USER
C


PATIENT
D,E,F


USER
G,H




And have you tried anything yourself?

"I want" is no question. Do you have one?

You should make sure column name and column value match. A "date" column should contain dates, not numbers.

You can achieve the desired output by using a combination of window functions, ARRAY_AGG, and STRING_AGG in PostgreSQL. Here's how you can write the SQL query:
WITH grouped_data AS (
    SELECT 
        date,
        sender_type, 
        content, 
        CASE 
            WHEN sender_type = LAG(sender_type) OVER (ORDER BY date) THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS is_new_group
    FROM 
        your_table_name
),
grouped_with_ids AS (
    SELECT 
        sender_type, 
        content,
        SUM(is_new_group) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS group_id
    FROM 
        grouped_data
)
SELECT 
    sender_type, 
    STRING_AGG(content, ',') AS content
FROM 
    grouped_with_ids
GROUP BY 
    sender_type, group_id
ORDER BY 
    MIN(date);

